# How to get detailed information with as.numeric function when coercing data?

Tags: r, csv

I have a big CSV file (more than 100,000 lines). Except the first column (which is the time), this file is supposed to contain only numeric values.

However, when I read the file using `read.csv` function, some of the data frame variables only contain characters.

I tried to convert those variables in numeric with the `as.numeric` function and then I get an warning message:

> Warning message:
>
> NAs introduced by coercion

My guess is that there is an error in how the CSV file is written. I want to fix that error, but to do that, I need to know where are the problems.

Is there a way to have more detailed information why (and especially where) `as.numeric` fails to convert my data to numeric?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help if you provided a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1217536).  Since you didn't, I'll try to make one.  Hopefully, this will be worthwhile.

```
write.csv(read.table(text="A 1  2   3
B   2   3   4
C   3   4   5
D   4   5   6
E   5   q   7
F   6   7   8
G   7   8   9", header=F, stringsAsFactors=F), file="file.csv", row.names=F)
```

This file should open with numeric variables (other than the first column), but the third column is screwed up somewhere:

```
my.data <- read.csv("file.csv", stringsAsFactors=F, header=T)
str(my.data)
# 'data.frame':  7 obs. of  4 variables:
#  $ V1: chr  "A" "B" "C" "D" ...
#  $ V2: int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7
#  $ V3: chr  "2" "3" "4" "5" ...
#  $ V4: int  3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

One thing you can try is to read in the file one row at a time, and see when the class of the variable in question switches from numeric:

```
for(i in 1:7){
  row <- read.csv("file.csv", stringsAsFactors=F, header=T, skip=i-1, nrows=1)
  if(is.character(row[1,3])){ break() }
}
i         # [1] 5
row[1,3]  # [1] "q"
```

Having discovered the culprit (or at least the first one), you could open the file in Excel, or something like [EditPad](https://www.editpadlite.com/), and navigate to the bad element and fix it.  (Be sure to do this to a *copy* of the file; keep the original—warts and all—for a permanent record.)

---

*Edit:*
If you already have a vector with `NA`s, you can find out where they are with:

```
which(is.na(as.numeric(my.data[,3])))
# [1] 5
# Warning message:
# In which(is.na(as.numeric(my.data[, 3]))) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

Or jump straight to inspecting the elements with:

```
my.data[which(is.na(as.numeric(my.data[,3]))),3]
# [1] "q"
# Warning message:
# In which(is.na(as.numeric(my.data[, 3]))) : NAs introduced by coercion
```